# How to add a class in a svg element (circle) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to add class to svg elements (circles) but, I am getting "[object SVGAnimatedString]" as an output when I am trying to display the classname on console. Entire Code available on fiddle : jsfiddle.net/prated/rsv0yxgx

```
<script>
  var counter =0;
  function selectForPValues()
  {

    var colorFormed = new Array("orange","green","blue","yellow","black","pink");
    var index = document.getElementsByClassName("selected").length;
    for(var i=0;i<index;i++)
     {
       textVar = document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[i].id;
       console.log("Id: "+ textVar);
       document.getElementById(textVar).className = "tester";
       document.getElementById(textVar).style.fill = colorFormed[counter];
       console.log("Resultant: "+ document.getElementById(textVar).className);
     }
    counter++;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [`SVGAnimatedString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString) in order to understand how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot add class to a svg with className , try

```
svg.setAttribute("class", "class Name");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, its not working for my code. How can I add class only to a particular element with id as "selected" which is a circle.

Comment: I have shared my code on https://jsfiddle.net/prated/rsv0yxgx/

Thanks for your help

Comment: i am not sure wat your trying to achive , have a look at the updated fiddle you can inspect each circle dots and find the classes are added

        https://jsfiddle.net/tjaemtka/

Comment: **Your solution is correct.**

document.getElementById(textVar).setAttribute("class","selected Trigger");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById(textVar).classList.add("tester");
```

Other potentially useful methods are `.remove` and `.toggle`.